# unexpected token: JELLY_SCRIPT in Jekins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jelly

When I'm trying to run this in Jenkins automation project,
I got this error,

```
WorkflowScript: 552: unexpected token: JELLY_SCRIPT @ line 552, column 27.
                       ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="testResults.jelly"}
```

I have added,to the email body  `${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="testResults.jelly"}` inside success stage.
Why is this problem occuring?

```
post {

            always {
               junit '**/results/*.xml'
            }


           success {
               emailext (
                   subject: "SUCCESSFUL: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'", to: '$EMAIL_LIST', attachmentsPattern: '**/results/*',attachLog: true,
                    body: """<p>UNSTABLE: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'</p>
                    <p>Check console output at ;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a></p> <br> Unit test: ${env.UNIT_TEST} <br> Integration test: ${env.INTEGRATION_TEST} <br> Upgrader test: ${env.UPGRADER_TEST} <br>
                    <h1>Unit Test Report</h1>

                    ${env.UNIT_TEST_REPORT}
                    <br> ${env.UPGRADER_REPORT}
                    <br> <h3>Find Upgrader Logs in following location : </h3><br>
                    ${env.FTP_PATH}
                    <br> ${env.FTP_LOCATION} <br> ${env.EMAIL_CONTENT}""",
                    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'UpstreamComitterRecipientProvider']]
               )
               cleanWs()
           }


           unstable {
               emailext (
                   subject: "UNSTABLE: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'", to: '$EMAIL_LIST', attachmentsPattern: '**/results/*',attachLog: true,
                   body: """<p>UNSTABLE: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'</p>
                   <p>Check console output at ;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a></p> <br> Unit test: ${env.UNIT_TEST} <br> Integration test: ${env.INTEGRATION_TEST} <br> Upgrader test: ${env.UPGRADER_TEST} <br>
                   <h1>Unit Test Report</h1>

                   ${env.UNIT_TEST_REPORT}
                   <br> ${env.UPGRADER_REPORT}
                   <br> <h3>Find Upgrader Logs in following location : </h3><br>
                   ${env.FTP_PATH}
                   <br> ${env.FTP_LOCATION} <br> ${env.EMAIL_CONTENT}""",
                   recipientProviders: [[$class: 'UpstreamComitterRecipientProvider']]
               )

               cleanWs()
           }

       }
```

above is the full code of email template. when add above ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="testResults.jelly"} inside email body, this error occured.

Comment: Can you show your full `emailext` step?

Comment: Hi, I added it.

Comment: I have the same problem. I think in practice people use Jenkins much less than it appears to outsiders. The lack or bad/misleading answers to problems about elementary usage also indicates that.